# Split pipe delimited into new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to split one column (pipe delimited) into new columns.

Ex: column 1: `Data|7-8|5`

it should be split into

```
col2          col3         col4
Data          7-8          5
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Is there always a fixed number of pipes?

Comment: Yes only two pipes .. Have to split into three columns

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: select  col1
, LEFT(col1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',col1)-1,-1),LEN(col1))) as col2 
,LEFT(col2,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',col1)-1,-1),LEN(col1))-1) as col3
,RIGHT(col1,LEN(col)-ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',col1)-1,-2),LEN(col1))) as col4
from mytable

Comment: I tried above query. I ma  getting col2 correctly but not able to split 2nd pipe into col3 and col4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a play with this. It's a little verbose but illustrates every step of the operation. I encourage you to ask any follow up questions you might have!

```
DECLARE @t table (
   piped varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t (piped)
  VALUES ('pipe|delimited|values')
       , ('a|b|c');

; WITH x AS (
  SELECT piped
       , CharIndex('|', piped) As first_pipe
  FROM   @t
)
, y AS (
  SELECT piped
       , first_pipe
       , CharIndex('|', piped, first_pipe + 1) As second_pipe
       , SubString(piped, 0, first_pipe) As first_element
  FROM   x
)
, z AS (
  SELECT piped
       , first_pipe
       , second_pipe
       , first_element
       , SubString(piped, first_pipe  + 1, second_pipe - first_pipe - 1) As second_element
       , SubString(piped, second_pipe + 1, Len(piped) - second_pipe) As third_element
  FROM   y
)
SELECT *
FROM   z
```

Answer (score 2):

test data:-

```
create table #test (
    col1 varchar(50)
)
go
insert into #test values
    ('Data|7-8|5'),
    ('Data|asdsad|sad'),
    ('fish|c cx cx xc cc xc cx |ededededeed'),
    ('Data|iueroiheqroqer|ewoijewijewd5'),
    ('tune||5'),
    ('Data||')
go
```

function (needs more defensive programming for malformed input):-

```
create function dbo.GetDomain(
    @source varchar(1024),
    @delimiter varchar(10),
    @domain int
) returns varchar(1024) as begin
    declare @returnValue varchar(1024)
    declare @workingOn int
    declare @length int
    set @workingOn=0
    while @workingOn<@domain begin
        set @source=substring(@source,charindex(@delimiter,@source)+1,1024)
        set @workingOn+=1
    end
    set @length=charindex(@delimiter,@source)
    set @returnValue=substring(@source,1,case when @length=0 then 1024 else @length-1 end)
    return @returnValue
end
go
```

useage:-

```
select t.col1, 
    dbo.GetDomain(t.col1,'|',0) as col2, 
    dbo.GetDomain(t.col1,'|',1) as col3, 
    dbo.GetDomain(t.col1,'|',2) as col4
from #test t
go
```

produces:-

```
col1                                     col2  col3                 col4
Data|7-8|5                               Data  7-8                  5
Data|asdsad|sad                          Data  asdsad               sad
fish|c cx cx xc cc xc cx |ededededeed    fish  c cx cx xc cc xc cx  ededededeed
Data|iueroiheqroqer|ewoijewijewd5        Data  iueroiheqroqer       ewoijewijewd5
tune||5                                  tune                       5
Data||                                   Data
```

Answer (score 0):

probably hundreds of better ways than this but

```
declare @string as varchar(100)
set @string = 'Data|7-8|5'
select left(@string,CHARINDEX('|',@string,0) -1) as one, 
left(substring(@string,CHARINDEX('|',@string,0)+1,100),CHARINDEX('|',substring(@string,CHARINDEX('|',@string,0)+1,100),0) -1) as two,
reverse(left(reverse(@string),CHARINDEX('|',reverse(@string),0) -1)) as three
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite approaches to this type of problem is to use the XML data type. I do not know much about the performance of it, but it does the job.

```
DECLARE @line VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @x xml;

/* example data */
SET @line = 'Data|7-8|5';


/* replace the delimeter with closing and opening tags,
   and wrap the line with opening and closing tags as well */
SET @x = Cast(
        '<field>'
        + replace(@line, '|', '</field><field>')
        + '</field>' AS XML);


/* query the nodes based on index */
SELECT
    @x.query('field[1]').value('.','VarChar(10)')   Col1
    ,@x.query('field[2]').value('.','VarChar(10)')  Col2
    ,@x.query('field[3]').value('.','Int')          Col3
```