# how to split pipe delimited column into new columns in hive sql?

Tags: sql, parsing

I have column where its values delimited by pipe operator in hive table, which is highly unstructured, and I would like to split this column that delimited by pipe and get corresponding columns which is more than many apparently. So, I need to first parse the string start with `HP1` then locate string between 30-40th pipe. I tried multiple of doing this, but not able to parse it correctly. Can anyone suggest possible workaround to do this in hive sql?

**sample data and my current attempt**

Here I pasted top 3 rows of my original data.

```
SSH|^~\&|EnsembleMK9|ISC|DELTA HIE^1.2.3.411593.135778^DEL|TESTMD|202209190035||ACK^A08|1214451793^137099156|P|2.5.1MSA|AA|1214451793^137099156
SSH|^~\&|DELTA HIE^1.2.3.411593.135778^DEL|PCCMM|LEAG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.140^DEL|HIVEDBAKG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.140^DEL|20220919053530.832||AKG^A08^AKG_A01|C1016708390|P|2.5.1|||NE||||||@SSH.3^NXG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.1000.1005.152.4.264^DEL~@SSH.4^PCCMM^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.124^DELEVN||20220919013529PID|1||5624118^^^PCCMM&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.2&DEL^MR||Anderson^Donald||19440711|M||2106-3^White|30 Pine Woods Road^^Hyde Park^NY^12538^USA||^PRS^PH^^1^845^2292777||^English|M||||||^Non-Hispanic||||||||N|||||||||PD1||||AA48^Diminico^Carlo^F^^^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.4&DEL^^^^^^^^^^^^^&&&&&&&&&PCP||||||||N|20220310ROL||AD|RCP|2022062001^^^^^^^^2.16.840.1.113883.4.6^^^^KOR^^^^^^^^HP|1|O|PKCL||||AA48^Diminico^Carlo^F^^^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.4&DEL^^^^^^^^^^^^||||||||||||73828528~86654484|||||||||||||||||||||||||202209190135
SSH|^~\&|PC^1.2.3.411593.135778^DEL|PC|LEAG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.140^DEL|HIVEDBAKG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.140^DEL|20220919053530.832||AKG^A08^AKG_A01|C1016708390|P|2.5.1|||NE||||||@SSH.3^NXG^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.1000.1005.152.4.264^DEL~@SSH.4^PCCMM^2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.100.0.0.255.124^DELEVN||20220919013529PID|1||5624118^^^PCCMM&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.2&DEL^MR||Anderson^Donald||19440711|M||2106-3^White|30 Pine Woods Road^^Hyde Park^NY^12538^USA||^PRS^PH^^1^845^2292777||^English|M||||||^Non-Hispanic||||||||N|||||||||PD1||||AA48^Diminico^Carlo^F^^^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.4&DEL^^^^^^^^^^^^^&&&&&&&&&PCP||||||||N|20220310ROL||AD|RCP|2022062001^^^^^^^^2.16.840.1.113883.4.6^^^^KOR^^^^^^^^HP|1|O|PKCL||||AA48^Diminico^Carlo^F^^^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.8932.101.4&DEL^^^^^^^^^^^^||||||||||||73828528~86654484||||||||||||||||||||PCCMM|||||202209190135
```

here is my first attempt:

based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688863/split-pipe-delimited-into-new-columns), I tried following:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT colm
       , CharIndex('|', colm) As first_pipe
  FROM   mytbl
)
, y AS (
  SELECT colm
       , first_pipe
       , CharIndex('|', colm, first_pipe + 1) As second_pipe
       , SubString(colm, 0, first_pipe) As first_element
  FROM   x
)
, z AS (
  SELECT colm
       , first_pipe
       , second_pipe
       , first_element
       , SubString(colm, first_pipe  + 1, second_pipe - first_pipe - 1) As second_element
       , SubString(colm, second_pipe + 1, LENGTH(colm) - second_pipe) As third_element
  FROM   y
)
SELECT *
FROM z
limit 10
```

but I have error because `CharIndex` doesn't work for hive sql.

Here is my another attempt:

```
SELECT
    colm,
    INSTR(colm, 'HP1') AS HP1_position,   -- Find the position of "HP1" in the string
    SUBSTR(colm, INSTR(colm, 'HP1')) AS substring_after_HP1,    -- Extract the substring after "HP1" until the end
    SPLIT(SUBSTR(colm, INSTR(colm, 'HP1')), '\|') AS pipe_split,       -- Split the substring by the pipe "|" delimiter
    pipe_split[39] AS extracted_value       -- Extract the 40th element from the split data
FROM
    mytbl
```

this query also don't work, because `pipe_split[39]` give me error.

Is there any workaround to pipe delimited column into new list of columns correctly in hive sql? can anyone suggest possible approach on that? Do I need to write dynamic sql instaed? if so, how? any ideas?

**objective**

I want to split pipe delimited column into new columns. How can I do this in hive sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try `FUNCTION`, I have created `string_split` wrapper to split data based on delimiter and return the values in separated column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Split50
(   
    @str varchar(max),
    @delim char(1), 
    @columnCnt int = 125
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT 
            nn = (nn - 1) / @columnCnt + 1, 
            nnn = 'value' + cast(((nn - 1) % @columnCnt) + 1 as varchar(10)), 
            value
        FROM (SELECT 
            nn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)),
            value
            FROM string_split(@str, @delim) aa
            ) aa
        where nn > 0
    ) bb
    PIVOT  
    (  
    max(value) 
    FOR nnn IN (    
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10,
        value11, value12, value13, value14, value15, value16, value17, value18, value19, value20,
        value21, value22, value23, value24, value25, value26, value27, value28, value29, value30,
        value31, value32, value33, value34, value35, value36, value37, value38, value39, value40,
        value41, value42, value43, value44, value45, value46, value47, value48, value49, value50,
        value51, value52, value53, value54, value55, value56, value57, value58, value59, value60,
        value61, value62, value63, value64, value65, value66, value67, value68, value69, value70,
        value71, value72, value73, value74, value75, value76, value77, value78, value79, value80,
        value81, value82, value83, value84, value85, value86, value87, value88, value89, value90,
        value91, value92, value93, value94, value95, value96, value97, value98, value99, value100,
        value101, value102, value103, value104, value105, value106, value107, value108, value109, value110,
        value111, value112, value113, value114, value115, value116, value117, value118, value119, value120,
        value121, value122, value123, value124, value125
     )  
    ) AS PivotTable 
);
```

And you can call it this way:

```
select * from fn_split50('SSH|^~\&|DELTA HIE^1.2.3.411593.135778^DEL|PCCMM', '|', DEFAULT);
```

First parameter is the string value
Second parameter is the delimiter
Third parameter is how many columns you want to be pre-provided, if there are more values then the provided value will wrap it to the next row.

You may test it out at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97f1cf/1) link.

Answer (score -2):

This query selects the column from the MyTable and then it splits the content of column (a string with | as a delimiter) into its constituent parts. It assigns these parts to new columns named first_element, second_element, and third_element. At the end, it limits the results to 10 rows.

```
SELECT column,
           split(colm, '\\|')[0] AS first_element,
           split(colm, '\\|')[1] AS second_element,
           split(colm, '\\|')[2] AS third_element
    FROM MyTable
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**